# To handle the Multiple Http Request from the Clients

Tags: jsp, servlets

> > In Servlet, whenever a client makes an HTTP request for a particular Servlet, then a thread was created to handle the multiple requests.
> > Whether the Servlet Container creates the thread or the Servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Servlet Container runs multiple threads to process multiple requests to a single servlet.